# How to pass the values of the daterangepicker to another php page

Tags: php, daterangepicker

I want to get the range selected in daterange picker one first page(say: first.php) in another php page(say: action2.php).Here is my HTML CODE for the daterange picker(in first.php):

```html
<div id="reportrange" 
     class="px-3 py-1"
     style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer;  border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

and the js code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format(
            'MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment()
                .subtract(1,
                    'month').endOf('month')
            ]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
});
</script>
```

Comment: There are many ways. You could use the session, localstorage, cookies or just pass them by query parameters in the URL

Comment: Is the datepicker part of an HTML `<form>`? Easiest would then be to fill a (hidden) field with the selected value.

Comment: @jrswgtr i am trying but i think there is some problem in my code. CAN YOU PLEASE HELP ME? I am not getting how to access the start dates and end dates.

Comment: @ReinderWit no it's not part of any <form>

Comment: You have the selected start- and enddate availabe in function `cb()`. In that function you can send those values to your PHP script. There are loads of samples available online on how to send data to a PHP script using jQuery. Post your code and we can help you out further...